# React Native app - Storing data using Realm

Tags: javascript, ios, json, react-native, realm

Still on the learning curve with React Native. I have read the Realm docs and other forums but cannot seem to find the answer to the seemingly simple notion of writing data to a Realm. For example;

In my code, I receive the data (list of users) from a local json file and am able to access and display their information.

The bit i'm struggling with is the onPress function `bookmarkItem`. Where on button press I want to `realm.write` certain data from a json file to Realm. How do i store the value of say `{{user.login.username}}` in my realm database??? Below is the code in question;

```
import { users } from '../config/data';
import Realm from 'realm'

 class Article {}
  Article.schema = {
  name: 'Article',
  properties: {
    key:  'data',
    image: 'data',
    title: 'data',
  }
};

let realm = new Realm({schema: [Article]});

class Feed extends Component {
  onLearnMore = (user) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', { ...user });
  };

  bookmarkItem = (user) => {
   realm.write(() => {
    realm.create('Article', {
     key: {{user.login.username}},
     image: {{ uri: user.picture.large}},
     title: {{user.name.first}},
   });
  });
 };


render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
          {users.map((user) => (
              <Card key={user.login.username}>
                  <CardItem header>
                      <Right>
                        <Button onPress={() => this.bookmarkItem(user)}>
                            <Icon name="bookmark" />
                        </Button>
                      </Right>
                  </CardItem>
                  <CardItem cardBody onPress={() => this.onLearnMore(user)}>
                      <Image source={{ uri: user.picture.large }}/>
                  </CardItem>
                   <CardItem content>
                              <Text>{user.name.first} {user.name.last}</Text>
                   </CardItem>
             </Card>
           ))}
     </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

Clearly I'm not understanding something with the use of schema data types and how and where to correctly execute my realm.write function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use `{{}}` outside the JSX elements in your render function. Instead of `{{user.login.username}}` just use `user.login.username` in your `realm.create` function.

Also for image you shouldn't use `uri: user.picture.large` just `user.picture.large` will be enough. You can later use that variable as a uri.

Comment: Hey Dani, thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Can I ask one more...I've saved the data to realm and intend to retrieve it in a separate component (bookmark screen for a bookmark/favorite function). I haven't really used state much before, how do you see state working in this process of saving and retrieving data between 2 components? Maybe to change the icon on save, but maybe there are places i will need to use state that I've not thought of? Thanks again. Duncan

Comment: I Duncan, state as the name suggests represents the current state of ur components. If you are using React then you should be using states. Hmm... I can see you have used `users` variable directly inside your components render function. It's not a good practice. You should declare users as a state i.e. `state = { users: 'a value' }`, and whenever you need to change the value of users u shoud use `this.setState({users: 'new value'})`. Behind the scenes `this.setState` handles all the constraints.

Comment: In short... Your React Components render the JSX based on the states.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. The `users` data will not change, just the screen it will be displayed in, Even if my components won't change is it still necessary to use state?

Comment: Yeah! It's necessary because you don't know if in the future you might wanna make the users data dynamic. Better safe than sorry